# Web application doesn't migrate in cluster mode

Tags: web-server, jboss, live-migration

I installed JBoss EAP 6.4.0 on two different virtual machines:

1. `Ubuntu Server 12.10, IP=192.168.0.20`
2. `Ubuntu Server 12.10, IP=192.168.0.23`

Then on each machine I edited the standalone-ha.xml file in `standalone/configuration` and replaced all occurrences of `127.0.0.1` with `0.0.0.0`, to allow other machines to connect to the JBoss server.
Then I run the server this way:

```
$ ./standalone.sh -c standalone-ha.xml -b 192.168.0.{20|23} -u 230.0.0.4 -Djboss.node.name=node{1|2}
```

I copied a distributable war file in `standalone/deployment` and I verified that the war file is executed in cluster mode: it says "`received new cluster view`" and I clearly saw the names of both nodes on the logs.

I then connected to each instance:

1. `http://192.168.0.20:8080/MyApp`
2. `http://192.168.0.23:8080/MyApp`

If I shutdown `machine 1`, I'm not able to get the web app's page on `http://192.168.0.23:8080/MyApp` and vice-versa. But shouldn't the application be transferred on the other machine since they're on the same cluster?

Comment: You need a load balancer like`mod_cluster` to implement failover.

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail on what you've done to diagnose this so far? Have you verified that you can see your app on both URLs before you shut down one node? Am I correct in assuming that the app loads, but you don't get your session information replicated or is it, as you say, that the app itself doesn't work?